# Falla en consulta sql con or_like

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estoy creando una aplicación para control vehicular  con codeigniter 3.0. 
La consulta SQL que realizo es la siguiente:

***MODEL***

```
private function dataParaProcedimiento($criteria){
    $this->db->select(  T_PADRON_NOMBRES    ." as nombres,".
                            T_PADRON_APELLIDO_PATERNO           ." as apellido_paterno,".
            T_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION_F_DESCRIPCION         ." as tipo_identificacion,".
                            T_PADRON_DOCUMENTO          ." as numero_identificacion,".
                            T_VEHICULOS_F_MARCA         ." as marca,".
            T_VEHICULOS_F_MODELO        ." as modelo,".
            T_VEHICULOS_F_PATENTE       ." as patente,".
            T_OBLEA_F_CODIGO            ." as codigo,")      
            ->from(T_PADRON)
            ->from(T_VEHICULOS)
            ->join(T_OBLEA, T_OBLEA_F_ID_VEHICULO." = ".T_VEHICULOS_F_ID_VEHICULO)
            ->join(T_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION, T_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION_F_ID_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION." = ".T_PADRON_TIPO_DOCUMENTO)
            ->join(T_PADRON_OBLEA, T_PADRON_OBLEA_F_ID_PADRON." = ".T_PADRON_ID_PADRON)
            ->where(T_PADRON_OBLEA_F_ID_PADRON." = ".T_PADRON_ID_PADRON)
            ->where(T_PADRON_OBLEA_F_ID_OBLEA." = ".T_OBLEA_F_ID_OBLEA)
            ->order_by(T_PADRON_APELLIDO_PATERNO,"ASC");    

    if($criteria){
        $this->db->like(T_PADRON_NOMBRES,$criteria)
                ->or_like(T_PADRON_APELLIDO_PATERNO, $criteria)
                ->or_like(T_PADRON_APELLIDO_MATERNO, $criteria);
    }
}
```

***VIEW***

En el view tengo solo un inputbox (`$criteria`) para realizar la búsqueda.

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){       
    $("#buttonBusqueda").click( function(){
        var inputBusqueda = $('#inputBusqueda').val();
        var selectedBusqueda = $('#select_busqueda').val();
        var url = "<?=base_url('index.php/principal/buscarPersonaParaProcedimiento')?>";
                    var params = "/"+selectedBusqueda+"/"+inputBusqueda
        var winParams="toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=100,left=100,height=400";
        window.open(url+params,"Pop Up",winParams);
    });

    $('#popup_values').change( function() {         
        var arr = JSON.parse($(this).val());
        $('#id_entity').val(arr[0].value);
        $('#entity').val($('#select_busqueda').val());
        $('#label_data').text('Datos Asociados:');
        var contentDtDd = $('#selected_data');
        contentDtDd.html('');           
        $.each(arr, function (index, item) {
            contentDtDd.append('<dt>'+item.title+'</dt>');
            contentDtDd.append('<dd>'+item.value+'</dd>');
        });
    });
```

**Código para armar la tabla**

```
<?php 
$this->load->view('comun/popup_header');
$html_table_rows = "";
    foreach ($list as $item):
        $html_table_rows.="<tr><td title='Usuario:'>".$item['apellido_paterno']." ".$item['apellido_materno']." ".$item['nombres']."</td>";
        $html_table_rows.="<td title='Tipo y Nro. de Doc.:'>".$item['tipo_identificacion']." ".$item['numero_identificacion']."</td>";
        $html_table_rows.="<td title='Vehiculo:'>".$item['marca']." ".$item['modelo']." ".$item['patente']."</td>";
        $html_table_rows.="<td title='Oblea Nº'>".$item['codigo']."</td></tr>";
    endforeach; ?>
```

HTML

```html
<div id="content" style="height: auto;" >    
 <div class="jumbotron" style="height: 33px;padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 45px;">     
        <h2 style="margin-top: 0px; text-align: center">Elegir Persona</h2>
 </div>   
 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <table class="table table-borderer">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Usuario</th>
                        <th>Tipo y Nro. de Doc.</th>
                        <th>Vehiculo</th>
                        <th>Oblea Nº</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="rows-selectable">
                        <?=$html_table_rows?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

***RESULTADO***

Cuando busco por nombre (`$criteria`) me muestra bien el resultado de la búsqueda:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***PROBLEMA***

El problema se da cuando busco por apellidos, que me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando debería mostrarme como el resultado anterior.

Gracias!

Comment: Podrías aclarar cuál es el resultado esperado (qué es lo que quieres lograr), el valor del parámetro que estás pasando (`$criteria`) y que es lo que deberíamos notar de la captura.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Lo que se espera que muestre es un solo resultado. Ya que cada usuario tiene registrado un auto y posee un número de oblea. Lo que pasa es que cuando se realiza la búqueda por apellido paterno o apellido materno, muestra al mismo usuario con todos los vehiculos y obleas de la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Has revisado que el valor de `$criteria` es el mismo que el ingresado en el `inputbox`? De ser así, agregalo a tu pregunta, para quién revise sepa que has visto eso y busque la solución por otro lado.

Comment: Sí, está revisado. Ahí le aguegue al respecto en la pregunta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @VaneVilte porque no retornas la sentencia completa y verificas realmente como estas construyendo tu SQL. Esto para poder debuguear, despues del if {} dale un return $this->db->last_query();

Comment: Hola Alfonso Carrasco. Lo voy a hacer y estaré publicando el resultado. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar también que haces con el resultado de la consulta? Es decir, ¿armas la tabla mediante PHP? Si es así, pon el código con el que lo haces. ¿Pasas el resultado al cliente como JSON? Si, es esto útlimo, el código que transforma y envía el resutlado como JSON y del lado cliente el código javascript que usas para poblar la tabla.

Comment: Sí. Ahí agregué. Gracias.

Comment: Me parece que el criterio de búsqueda es peligroso porque me encontrado a mis propios nombres y apellidos en un club en la facultad etc, Yo haría la búsqueda por DNI que tiene que ser irrepetible a menos que tenga mas de un vehículo a su nombre.

Answer (score 0):

creo que no es una solución muy optima pero podrias intentar hacer algo como esto.

```
    if($criteria){
     $condicion="(T_PADRON_NOMBRES LIKE '".$criteria."' OR T_PADRON_APELLIDO_PATERNO LIKE '".$criteria."' OR T_PADRON_APELLIDO_MATERNO LIKE '".$criteria."')";
     $this->db->where($condicion);
    }
```